# How do I check for harmful registrations in Castle Windsor

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

We are making use of Castle Windsor's typed factories in our application and finding that, while they do "hide" the IoC container from the application, some of the abstraction is certainly leaking through. That is, the factories must implement a release method so that resolved instances can be safely disposed or otherwise decommissioned. After all, you never know when something in the component's "burden", i.e. downstream dependencies, will be introduced that might require new semantics. Therefore, you always assume (in effect) that everything you return from a typed factory is `IDisposable` -- that is, you should keep track of it and give it back. For this reason, we like to return `IReference<T>` objects whose `Dispose` method returns them to the factory in order to enforce this behavior, rather than depending on the kindness of strangers to call that release method.

However, there are many cases where we are highly confident that a service type will not require these semantics. And we know that Castle Windsor will even not bother tracking truly transient objects with no downstream burden. The garbage collector will do fine. In this case, we'd be happy with a factory that had no return method. Users can just let garbage collection do its thing.

What we'd like to do is inspect the registrations of the kernel and the typed factory facilities after all the typed factories have been registered to see if these assumptions have been violated. That is, issue a warning for any typed factory method which returned a type which did not have `IDisposable` semantics but ended up being registered with a burden which did. (It might be necessary to customize this; for instance depending on an app-wide singleton, or per-request objects  could be acceptable).

What are the best public interfaces to use to start querying and/or enforcing these conventions? Or should we perhaps just stop using so many typed factories?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think that the configurable Release Policies are what you are after, specifically the No Tracking release policy mentioned here: http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/castle-windsor-transient-objects-and-release-policies

Comment: I do very much want to track components that need to be tracked -- just want to be warned when I'm possibly letting one leak outside of the small number of composition roots in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar is shown in [this post](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-three-a-testing-your-first-installer.ashx) by Krzysztof. It shows how to unit test your registration code to make sure everything is correctly registered in the container.

Comment: Indeed I can see if they are registered, but what I want to know is if their downstream dependencies have disposable semantics. I think the language of Windsor, I want to know if the service type does not implement IDisposable, yet the Burden has decommission concerns.